# nanosleep sleep 60 microseconds too long

Tags: linux, cpu, sleep

I have the following test compiled in  g++  which nanosleep too long , it takes
 60 microseconds to finish , I expected it cost only less than 1 microsecond :

```
int main()
{
    gettimeofday(&startx, NULL);
    struct timespec req={0};
    req.tv_sec=0;
    req.tv_nsec=100 ;
    nanosleep(&req,NULL) ;
    gettimeofday(&endx, NULL);
    printf("(%d)(%d)\n",startx.tv_sec,startx.tv_usec);
    printf("(%d)(%d)\n",endx.tv_sec,endx.tv_usec);
    return 0 ;
}
```

My environment :  uname -r  showes :

```
3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
```

cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep HZ

```
CONFIG_NO_HZ_COMMON=y
# CONFIG_HZ_PERIODIC is not set
# CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE is not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y
# CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL_ALL is not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
# CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_300 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_1000=y
CONFIG_HZ=1000
CONFIG_MACHZ_WDT=m
```

Should I do something in HZ config so that nanosleep will do exactly I expect?!

my cpu information :

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                24
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2643 v3 @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               3600.015
BogoMIPS:              6804.22
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23
```

Edit :

```
#ifdef SYS_gettid
    pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    printf("thread1...tid=(%d)\n",tid);
#else
    #error "SYS_gettid unavailable on this system"
#endif
```

this will get tid of the thread I like to high priority , then do 
chrt -v -r -p 99 tid   to  achieve this goal , thanks for Johan Boule
kind help , great appreciate !!!

Edit2 :

```
#ifdef SYS_gettid
    const char *sched_policy[] = {
    "SCHED_OTHER",
    "SCHED_FIFO",
    "SCHED_RR",
    "SCHED_BATCH"
    };
    struct sched_param sp = {
        .sched_priority = 99
    };
    pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    printf("thread1...tid=(%d)\n",tid);
    sched_setscheduler(tid, SCHED_RR, &sp);
    printf("Scheduler Policy is %s.\n", sched_policy[sched_getscheduler(0)]);
#else
    #error "SYS_gettid unavailable on this system"
#endif
```

this will do exact  what I want to do  without help of chrt

Comment: g++ is a C++ compiler, not C compiler.

Comment: What leads you to believe that there is a 100ns timer available anywhere on Linux, or that the overhead of a system call doesn't overwhelm it?

Comment: this is by design, read notes section http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep. If you need to wait for a very little time your only option is "to burn" the CPU cycles.

Comment: @bmargulies ,  I am trying to achieve it  , and trying to figure out how to do it .

Comment: Have you tried to replace `gettimeofday` with `clock_gettime` using the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` ?

Comment: @JohanBoule , thanks , I will try it later , thanks for kindly reply .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is not an answer)

For what is worth, using the more modern functions leads to the same result:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec startx, endx;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &startx);
    struct timespec req={0};
    req.tv_sec=0;
    req.tv_nsec=100 ;
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &req, NULL);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &endx);
    printf("(%d)(%d)\n",startx.tv_sec,startx.tv_nsec);
    printf("(%d)(%d)\n",endx.tv_sec,endx.tv_nsec);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Output:

```
(296441)(153832940)
(296441)(153888488)
```

Comment: @ my box showes :  (15715524)(919434367)  , (15715524)(919488098), still around 55 microseconds ,  too long . any idea to make it less ?!

Comment: Running the program with `sudo chrt -v -r 99 ./a.out` makes it lower, fluctuating with a lower bound of about 5 microseconds.

`chrt --deadline` could probably do better, but is unfortunately not recognised on my system.

Comment: You might like to read this : http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html

Comment: thanks , you really help a lot , that is very close to my needs ,  then I have one more question ,  The c application I have is a multithread structure using pthread library , chrt said "chrt - manipulate real-time attributes of a process"  ,  Can it narrow downed to one thread of  that application ?!  no need all threads of that application to that high priority , Can I do that ?!

Comment: , I figure out using gettid  to achieve , thanks for kindly help , see Edit for details , you really help a lot .